# OkHttpClient leaking connection when using byteStream

Tags: java, android, okhttp, connection-leaks

I keep getting a connection leaked warning in my Logcat messages, even though I've closed every single body of every request I send out.

I have two wrapper methods for GET and POST requests, which initiate the request and pass back the response.

```
protected Response getRequest(String url, OkHttpClient client) throws IOException, SMUserLoggedOutException {
    // Create the builder.
    Request.Builder getRequestBuilder = new Request.Builder();

    // Set URL.
    getRequestBuilder.url(url);

    // Set Headers.
    setHeaders(getRequestBuilder, REQUEST_TYPE_GET);

    // Build the request.
    Request getRequest = getRequestBuilder.build();

    // Fire
    Response getResponse = client.newCall(getRequest).execute();

    // Check for logout.
    if (checkForLogout(getResponse) && !mIgnoreLoggedOutExceptions) {
        // Close body.
        getResponse.body().close();

        // Throw logged out exception.
        throw new SMUserLoggedOutException("User logged out");
    }

    // Return the response.
    return getResponse;
}

protected Response postRequest(String url, RequestBody formBody, OkHttpClient client) throws IOException, SMUserLoggedOutException {
    // Create the builder.
    Request.Builder postRequestBuilder = new Request.Builder();

    // Set URL.
    postRequestBuilder.url(url);

    // Set Headers.
    setHeaders(postRequestBuilder, REQUEST_TYPE_POST);

    // Set POST body.
    postRequestBuilder.post(formBody);

    // Build the request.
    Request postRequest = postRequestBuilder.build();

    // Fire.
    Response postResponse = client.newCall(postRequest).execute();

    // Check for logout.
    if (checkForLogout(postResponse) && !mIgnoreLoggedOutExceptions) {
        // Close response body.
        postResponse.body().close();

        // Throw logged out exception.
        throw new SMUserLoggedOutException("User logged out");
    }

    // Return the response.
    return postResponse;
}
```

I have a third method which handles converting the response body to a string via reading the `InputStream` via the responses `body().byteStream()` like so.

```
protected String getResponseBodyAsString(Response response) throws IOException {
    // Reference the input stream.
    InputStream inputStream;

    String contentEncodingHeader = response.header(HEADER_CONTENT_ENCODING);
    if (contentEncodingHeader != null && contentEncodingHeader.equals(STRING_GZIP)) {
        // Read the zipped contents.
        inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(response.body().byteStream());
    } else {
        // Read the normal contents.
        inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
    }

    // Create and return buffered reader.
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    // Read stream.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line.trim());
    }

    // Close everything.
    response.body().close();

    // I realize this isn't needed, but I kept getting warnings so
    // I figured, what the hell.
    inputStream.close(); 
    br.close();

    // Return the string.
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Every single `getRequest()` or `postRequest()` I call is followed by the `getResponseBodyAsString()` method, and if the user is logged out between requests, the body is closed as well. Yet I'm still getting connection leaked warnings..

If you need any other code, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks ahead of time.

**EDIT**

Another block of code, dunno if will help.  Every single object which calls `getRequest()` or `postRequest()` is encapsulated in an `ASyncTask` object which catches any exceptions.

```
try {
    // Execute the main task.
    success = mTransferObjectBase.run();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Save exception.
    mException = e;

    // Cancel the task.
    cancel(true);
}
```

Now, there's nothing closing the the `body()` of a response in these, however, In zero cases when I see the leak warning, is the `ASyncTask` cancelled.  So there can't be any exceptions which are preventing it from being closed.

**EDIT2**

After reading this [post](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2132), I realized that GZIP is not handled transparently, if you manually add the "Accept-Encoding...gzip" header. Removing the manual addition does allow it to be decoded transparently, however, I only get a single line of the document in the response body.

*GZIP handled transparently*

> <td align="center"><img width="208" height="110" src="images/alert_loginlogo.gif" /></td

That's all I get back, literally. If I handle decoding the stream myself, I get the entire document without issue.

Could this be a bug in the library, I'm at a loss here.

Comment: I don't know it is this, but you should probably put the response.body().close() in a finally block in case you occasionally get exceptions.

Comment: The other curious thing is why you are doing the GZIPInputStream part yourself.  This should normally be handled transparently for you.

You are definitely leaking native resources by not closing the GZIPInputStream. see http://kohsuke.org/2011/11/03/quiz-time-memory-leak-in-java/

Comment: If I am missing something please let me know, but doesn't closing the BufferedReader close the corresponding stream it's reading from? In this case, the GZIPInputStream? I tried getting the response using `...body().string()`, but I kept getting binary.

Comment: Yep. My bad about the gzip stream

Comment: If you can work out why the gzip isn't transparently happening, and don't really care about trim(). Then you could simplify this mostly down to response.body().string()

Comment: Edited question to explain why I'm handling the GZIP decoding.

Comment: probably best to raise a bug at https://github.com/square/okhttp especially if you can extract a simple test case against a public site.  Sorry, I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Yeah, I just opened an issue, working on a test case now